# Find methods that are only and only decorated by an annotation

Tags: typescript

Given the following example:

```
 function Flag(): void { /*Empty*/ }

 class Test {
     @Flag
     methodForTest(): void { /*Empty*/ } 
 }
```

I would like to do a code analysis for instance and find all the methods of `Test` which have been decorated by the `Flag` annotation.

For example:

```
 const p = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(Test);
 const methods = Reflect.ownKeys(p!);
```

How can I find the annotation attributes in a static way without having to return a function inside the decorator?

Comment: If the decorator doesn't _do_ anything, there's no way to tell which methods it was called with.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: So there is no way to use the way we do in C# or Java, is that right?

Comment: You could analyze the code statically by parsing the source code to generate an AST and then analyzing that AST to find specifically decorated methods within classes. Would that be an option?

Comment: @StefanK: Do you mean I write a compiler? :D Wow, that's surely not an option here as it is not worth the effort. I wanted to know if TypeScript supports what I asked or not. That's all.

Comment: I see, I just thought it might be an option :)
You also wouldn't have to write a parser yourself, there are enough libraries out there that take code as input and provide an abstract syntax tree as output. Then you just have to do a bit of tree traversal and that's it. So it wouldn't be that hard.